# Login with Flask framework

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I follow along with Flask tutorial and have question about these set of login function code (it has HTML part and Python part):

HTML part:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
{% if error %}
    <p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
{% endif %}
    <form action="" method=post>
        <dl>
            <dt>Username:
            <dd><input type=text name=username value="{{request.form['username']}}">
            <dt>Password:
            <dd><input type=password name=password>
        </dl>
        <p><input type=submit value=Login>
    </form>
```

Python part:

```
@app.route('/log', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    return render_template('log.html', error=error)
```

This code work as usual. I have to type `admin` to the username box and `password` box to get logged in. My question is about these four lines in HTML part:

```
<dt>Username:
<dd><input type=text name=username value="{{request.form['username']}}">
<dt>Password:
<dd><input type=password name=password>
```

Why, when I only put this `value="{{request.form['username']}}"` into `username`, the log-in process still work properly? Doesn't it has to be like this, to work properly?

```
<dt>Username:
<dd><input type=text name=username value="{{request.form['username']}}">
<dt>Password:
<dd><input type=password name=password value="{{request.form['password']}}">
```

Comment: Did you mean `<dd><input type=password name=password value="{{request.form['password']}}">`?

Comment: yes, ^^" sry. I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I believe you are confused about the purpose of setting `value="{{request.form['username']}}"` in the username field.

Let's walk through a login example:

- When you navigate to `/log` the associated view function renders `log.html`. The value of `request.form['username']` is not set at this point, so the username field is rendered with an empty string as value. The password also gets an empty string by default.
- After you enter the username and password and click submit the route will be invoked again as a `POST` request and both `request.form['username']` and `request.form['password']` will be set to the values entered by the user.
- Now you have two possibilities:

  - If the username and password are correct, then the user is logged in and redirected elsewhere in the app. The fact that the username field in the form had the value set to `request.form['username']` caused absolutely no effect, because at this point the HTML form is not used anymore.
  - If the username and/or password are incorrect, then the login form will be rendered again for the user to retry. Having the value of the username field set to `request.form['username']` will cause the username field to be remembered, the value that the user entered the first time will be shown this second time. The password, on the other side, will be shown empty again.

Remembering the username on a failed login attempt is a convenience feature. You can edit it and make a correction if there is a mistake.

Doing this on the password field makes no sense though, because you cannot see the characters so you don't know if you have to make a correction. For passwords you always have to type them again from scratch.

Comment: Crystal clear my master! thank you soooo much. So the input name tag in HTML name=username and name=password will be send to the python to evaluate True or False with this part of code right?  if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':  ? am I understand correctly?

Comment: Right, the HTML does not really have any logic associated with it, all it defines is the values that then are sent to the view function.